# Is it possible to allow multiple Remote Desktop connexions in Windows 7 pro?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Is it possible to allow multiple Remote Desktop (for multiple users) connexions in Windows 7 pro?

- Without using some opaque non-open source patch preferably.

I know it was possible in XP pro, but, I found nothing interesting for Seven...

Comment: I take it you mean you want multiple users to connect TO a Windows 7 Professional computer, all at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it's possible.  I've seen a set of relatively simple instructions for how to do it.  However, it requires replacing a system file that should not be touched (ie: you'll either break your windows updates or have your changes broken when the updates are applied) and it's a major violation of the license.

So for all practical purposes you should just pretend that it can't be done.

> I know it was possible in XP pro

The same advice applies for XP.  It was possible, but only by violating your license and replacing a system file with an "opaque, non-open source" equivalent of unknown quality.

Comment: `unknown quality` and possibly a rootkit. That's what I thought, it's not only a violation of the license, but it also creates a significant potential security risk...

Comment: The precedent sysadmin of one of my client create a server with Windows 7 like this. Now, I would like to audit it, so: 1) What is the name of the system file replaced, and the manipulation done? 2) Is it possible to reverse the manipulation, or preferable to reinstall the whole system?

Comment: Precisions: The strange thing about this computer is that Windows update work perfectly, and `SFC /scannow` don't replace the patched file (if this is the way used bay this sysadmin)...

Comment: I don't remember where I found the instructions, but I do remember part of the process was editing something to trick sfc into believing this file was the original.

Answer (score 4):

No, the Remote Desktop feature of Windows 7 only allows a single user to connect at a time.  To have a machine which allows multiple people to connect at once you would need a Server OS such as Windows 2008 R2 and some Terminal Server Licenses.

Answer (score 2):

Desktop versions of Windows are only licensed for 1 concurrent interactive user. Any method which would allow more than 1 interactive user at a time would also be a violation of the EULA. Don't violate your license. Get a server OS along with Remote Desktop Services licenses.